# matplotlib - How to add pixel size legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.misc
lena = sp.misc.lena()

plt.imshow2(lena)
```

What I'd like is then to add a bar indicative of distance. ie suppose this was an actual image captured with a camera and I knew that each pixel corresponds to 1cm. I would want to add a bar that is 10 x 100 pixels and add some text that says 1m above the bar. Is there a simple way to do this?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In the example bellow I made a simple solution of your problem. It should not be too hard to extend this to cover a more general case. Hardest thing to get right here is the `pos_tuple`.

Since `pos_tuple` represents the upper left corner of `Rectangle` you have to subtract the length of the bar itself and then still leave some padding, otherwise it will be plotted at the very edge of the graph and look ugly. So a more general `pos_tuple` would look something like

`pos_tuple = (np.shape(lena)[0]-m2pix(1)-padding_right, 
              np.shape(lena)[1]-m2pix(0.1)-padding_bottom)`

This whole thing could also be adapted into a neat function `add_image_scale` that would take in your figure and spit out a figure which has the scale "glued" on. `m2pix` could also be generalized to receive a scale instead of hardcoding it.

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.misc
import numpy as np

lena = sp.misc.lena()

def m2pix(pix): #it takes a 100 pix to make a meter
    return 100*pix

pos_tuple = (np.shape(lena)[0]-100-12, np.shape(lena)[1]-10-2)
rect = plt.Rectangle( pos_tuple, m2pix(1), m2pix(0.1))
plt.imshow2(lena)
plt.gca().add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

As far as adding text goes, you can use the [annotations](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html) or [text](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_intro.html) which are both very easy to use.